# Listar app iniciadas

Tags: android

Intento hacer una pequeña app que evite que se inicien determinadas aplicaciones. He visto [ResolveInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo) y [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager), pero sólo veo info sobre las app ya instaladas y necesitaria saber que app se quiere abrir para permitir acceso.

Algo parecido a un control paternal...

Por donde puedo empezar?
Gracias!!

Comment: Tu pregunta es un poco amplia...No entiendo lo que pides "***necesitaria saber que app se quiere abrir para permitir acceso***"  si ya tienes las apps instaladas porque no bloqueas las que deseas ?

Comment: Bueno.... Aún no he empezado la app. Solo he intentado ver como hacerla, por eso no puedo ser más específico. La idea de la app es la de control parental. Si le doy el terminal a mi hijo para que coma un poco más se pone a abrir aplicaciones que no quiero que abra. Mi idea es la de crear un servicio que permita, o no, la ejecución de determinadas aplicaciones. Lo que necesito es saber con que clases trabajar. Muchas gracias de todos modos!!!!

Comment: leyendo un poco he visto que google play tiene un servicio de Control Parental en donde creas usuarios y demás con distintos permisos no se si eso te ayuda.Si lo que quieres es crear la app al final tendrás que listar las aplicaciones instaladas e implementar el típico switch de ON/OFF

Answer (score 1):

se puede hacer atraves del activity manager que devuelve las apps que estan corriendo actualmente 
intenta algo asi

```
 final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

 for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++){
 Log.d("Executed app", "Application executed : "+recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
 }
```

Comment: getRunningTasks() es obsoleta desde Android 5.0

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!
Creo que es lo que estaba buscando....

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una respuesta diciendo "gracias". En su lugar, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que consideres como la mejor solución a tu problema. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/170858)

Comment: @eusebiomontero si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada pulsando en el icono de la parte superior izquierda.